# how to check if a number is of 4 digits in c++?

Tags: c++

How to check if a number is of 4 digits in c++?
I have tried this code:

```
bool check4(int number)
{
     if ((number % 10) && !(number / 10000) && (number / 1000) && (number / 100) && (number / 10))
         return true;
     else
         return false;
}
```

It works only for numbers that not contain 0, like 1234 , 5678 etc.

Can someone show me how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Not the problem, but too many parentheses.

Answer (score 16):

What about this:

```
return (number > 999) && (number < 10000);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could just check that `number > 999` and `number <= 9999` rather than doing all the decimal manipulation.

```
bool check4(int number)
{
     return number > 999 && number <= 9999;
}
```

Comment: Sorry , but this is not the general case.

Comment: OP  always expects a better answer.

Comment: @ShivamSharma you consider your loop a better answer?

Comment: @ShivamSharma OP asked for a precise thing. If OP wanted the general case they should have asked for it.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 simple ways:

- Check the range ( number > 999 and number < 10000 )
- Take decimal logarithm and check that integral part is equal to 3

Answer (score 1):

You can apply for 4 digits number-->

```
 return number > 999 && number <= 9999
```

**NOTE:** you can apply also for **any length(n) of number**.

```
 int length=0,num;

    while((num= num/10) >0)
    {
    length++;
    if(length == n && num==0)                  //n is the expected length of number.
    {
    std::cout<<"number is of  digit";
    break;
    }
```

Comment: Your loop stops when length == n, and reports the number as having n digits, even if it has more.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a math.log

```
return log10(number) == 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    enteragain:
    cout << "-----Enter a Number----\n";
    int number;
    char choice;
    cin >> number;
    if (number> 999 && number <10000 ) {
        cout << "\nNumber is four digit\n";
        cout << "Would You like enter another number? press y for yes or n for no = ";
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 'y')
        {
            goto enteragain;
        }
        if (choice == 'n')
        {
            goto nowexit;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not a four digit number \n";
        goto enteragain;
    }
    nowexit:

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: it's good to describe your answer in words to support the code you have here

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int year;
    cout << "Enter Year: ";
    cin >> year;
    if (year < 1000 || year > 9999) {
        cout << "Invalid entry. \n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to do it by decimal manipulations, try this

```
if((n/1000)>0&&(n/10000)==0)
    {
    //four digit number
    }
```

In your code `(number % 10)` is causing the problem.

Comment: Why even bring division into it?  Your doing 4 steps instead of 2.